# SPA + back button + form state

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I am converting a jsp multi-page app(mpa) into a React single-page app (spa). In the mpa, the back button worked and *the form retained its state*.

In my new React app, the back button works but the form does *not* retain its state.

Question: is there a trick to make my form retain its state after "backing" to it (in an spa).

Here are the two solutions I came up with:

1. Encode the entire form state into the url. Then update the browser history with an updated url every time the form changes. But, this seems like a huge pain in the butt.
2. Modify the structure of my app such that the form in question (a React Component) stays mounted (and just use the css visibility or display property to show and hide). But, in a large app, leaving every page mounted in the DOM seems like it might lead to performance problems.

By the way, I am using popstate and the browser history api to achieve SPA behavior (i.e. i have rolled my own router) as described [here](https://medium.com/@daveford/react-router-alternative-switch-acd7961f08db#.ha055vha3).

Hopefully someone can propose a solution that is better than my two solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Redux to have a `state` store which transcends any particular component.  Then in your component, as part of the form submission process, `dispatch` an `action` with `payload` of all of the form data.  This should be cached on state and then when the component is remounted by your navigation structure, it should have access to this cache via Redux`s`connect`function`s `mapStateToProps` method.  You can repopulate your form from that.

It's not clear from your question whether or not you are submitting the `form` in the traditional old way.  I would use `e.preventDefault` in the handler instead, and have all the form data on the component's `state`, this can be sent to Redux's `state` store as described above, and Ajaxed off with [superagent](http://redux.js.org) or similar.  At the same time it can be cached.

Redux: http://redux.js.org

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using something similar to Wylie Кулик's answer with a few changes:

1. I didn't want to switch to Redux for just this one use-case. So I used the component *state* of my top-level component (i.e. a component higher up the tree).
2. I cached the form's state on the form component's componentWillUnmount and restored the cached state on componentDidMount.
3. I passed the cached state as a prop from the higher component to the child component.

It ended up being a very small amount of code and is working like a charm so far.